# How to edit my code to create an n by n array of any size from inputs

Tags: python

I am working on creating an eigenvalue calculator and my current one can find eigenvalues in 4 by 4 matrices but I want the user to be able to define how big they want the n by n matrix. They can define how many rows in the matrix but I want that to also define how may columns there are as well.

```
from numpy import array, zeros, diag, diagflat, dot
from math import *
import numpy as np
n = int(input("How many rows in the matrix: "))

row1values = []
row2values = []
row3values = []
row4values = []
bvalues = []
for i in range(n):
    row1 = float(input('row 1 value number ' + str(i + 1) + ' : '))
    row2 = float(input('row 2 value number ' + str(i + 1) + ' : '))
    row3 = float(input('row 3 value number ' + str(i + 1) + ' : '))
    row4 = float(input('row 4 value number ' + str(i + 1) + ' : '))
    b = float(input('b value number ' + str(i + 1) + ' : '))
    row1values.append(row1)
    row2values.append(row2)
    row3values.append(row3)
    row4values.append(row4)
    bvalues.append(b)


The result works for 4 by 4 matrices.
```

Comment: If the matrix is `n x n` the number of rows equals the number of columns. What is the point of entering it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
# get your row and column size
n = int(input("rows"))
m = int(input("cols"))
# create a list of indices for your array
from itertools import product
indices = list(product(np.arange(n), np.arange(m)))
# create an empty array of your desired size
array = np.zeros((n,m)).astype(float)
# fill in values your array
for i,j in indices:
    array[i,j] = float(input('input ({},{}) '.format(i,j)))
```